# Would this philosophy-of-science question be on-topic on Philosophy.SE?

Tags: discussion, allowed-topics

A questions on Physics SE just got closed as *off-topic* for being a philosophy question:

[Is the idea of dividing the universe into particles anything more than an untrue convenience?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/50062/6319)

Would this question be on-topic on Philosophy?

Comment: Thanks gerrit. I had already posted before I saw this. http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/4751/is-the-idea-of-dividing-the-universe-into-particles-anything-more-than-a-conveni

Answer (score 2):

It's worded a bit "physics-y" but the underlying philosophical notions behind it are on-topic, and indeed interesting. My only concern is that the OP seems to know the answer to his own question already and is looking for more of a discussion, but other than that it's fine.